# React TS useContext and UseReducer with axios

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-context, use-reducer

I am making an Axios call to get data. What should be the type for Axios call? For now, the type is any but how can I make it more strict?

```
import axios from "axios";
import { createContext, useEffect, useContext, useReducer } from "react";
import { Action, LevelsType, State, StateContextType, StateProviderPropsType } from "../Types/types";

const LevelCtx = createContext({} as StateContextType);

export function LevelProvider({children}:StateProviderPropsType) {

    const initialState:State = {
        levels: null
    }

    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
           const response = await axios.get<any>("http://localhost:5000/levels"); // Fix required.

            return dispatch({type: "SET_LEVELS", payload: response.data.levels})
            

        })();
        
    }, [])


    function reducer(state:State, action: Action) {
        switch (action.type) {
            case "SET_LEVELS":
                return {...state, levels: action.payload }
        
            default:
                return state
        }
    }

    console.log("levelCTX", state);

    return (
        <LevelCtx.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
            {children}
        </LevelCtx.Provider>
    )
};

export function useLevelCtx() {
    return useContext(LevelCtx);
}
```

My types file looks like this -

```
import { ReactNode }from "react";

export type LevelsObjectType = {
    _id: string;
    img: string;
    levelName: string;
    __v: number;
}

export type LevelsType = {
    levels: LevelsObjectType[]
}

export type State = {
    levels: LevelsType[] | null;
}

export type StateProviderPropsType = {
    children: ReactNode;
}

export type StateContextType = {
    state: State;
    dispatch: React.Dispatch<Action>;
}

export type Action = 
    | { type: "SET_LEVELS"; payload: LevelsType[] }

export type ServerError = {
    errorMessage: string;
}
```

The data I am getting from the api call is this -
[image]

Now after doing this when i try to map over state.levels, it throw the following error -

[image]

I tried adding LevelsType to the above axios call but it is throwing an error. I am trying to setup useRecuder and useContext using React TS. I am new to typescript. So please help me figure out this.

Comment: please post your code instead of an image.

Answer (score 0):

You could have two types:

```
export type LevelsObjectType = {
    _id: string;
    img: string;
    levelName: string;
    __v: number;
}

export type LevelsObjectTypeResult = {
    levelsObjects: LevelsObjectType[],
    success: boolean
}
```

And return:

```
await axios.get<LevelsObjectTypeResult>("http://localhost:5000/levels")
```

In the reducer:

```
 return {...state, levels: action.payload.levelsObjects }
```

Comment: I tried to do as you said, but that is not working. Also, I have edited the question to be more specific about the problem. Sorry for not being specific earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because of the way your `State` type is defined

```
export type State = {
    levels: LevelsType[] | null;
}
```

When you do `state.levels.map(level)`, level type is `LevelsType` which you defined like this

```
export type LevelsType = {
    levels: LevelsObjectType[]
}
```

so you are trying to access `_id` on a `LevelsType` object and obviously typescript complains about it since `_id` doesn't exist in `LevelsType`.

Try this:

```
export type State = {
    levels: LevelsObjectType[] | null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can `destructure` Axios and extract the data response from the response object or the Axios response schema. The `data` property is the server response and virtually will give some sort of type to the response object.

The code I'm putting up will only focus on some types/interfaces in your code and techniques for making Axios get requests without using `any` data type.

It could be like this for example.

```js
// types

export type LevelsObjectType = {
    _id: string;
    img: string;
    levelName: string;
    __v: number;
}

export type State = {
    levels: LevelsObjectType[]; 
}

export const initialState: State = {
  levels: [], // initial state is empty array and not null
}

// ...
```

I'm going to separate the business logic of fetching the resources into its own module. e.g. `services` directory.

```js
import axios from 'axios'
import { LevelsObjectType } from './types'

const clientCall = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000',
  headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
  },
})

const retrieveAllLevels = async () => {
  // could be translated as ===> const levelsListFromApi: LevelsObjectType[]
  const { data: levelsListFromApi } = await clientCall.get<LevelsObjectType[]>('/levels')
  return levelsListFromApi

// ...

const levelService = {
  retrieveAllLevels,
// ...
}

export default levelService
```

In the component e.g. App

```js
import React, { useEffect, useContext } from 'react'
import levelService from './services/level'
//...

const App: React.FC = () => {
const { state, dispatch } = useContext(YouStateContext)

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchLevels = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await levelService.retrieveAllLevels()
        //console.log(response)
        dispatch({ type: 'SET_LEVELS', payload: response })
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
      }
    }
    fetchLevels()
  }, [dispatch])

}

const levels = Object.values(state.levels) // begin mapping this array on return
//console.log(levels)

// ...
```

Just give it a shot, and hopefully it will work.

Happy coding!